# Software for doing math “by hand”

Tags: ios, math, iphone-app, drawing

I’m using Khan Academy to brush up on my math skills.

**Is there an iPhone app that will let me work out problems “by hand” so I can avoid using actual paper?**

I tried using the built-in Notes app, but it looks very messy, very fast, and I quickly run out of room.

[image: Division in Notes app]

I’m *not* looking for the software to perform calculations or check my work. I just want to be able to easily write the problems as if I were using paper.

OCR (conversion of handwritten numbers & symbols to text) would be nice, but only if it is more help then hindrance.

Comment: The MyScript stack of apps looked promising, especially their MathPad app, but it won’t work with writing out math problems in the step-by-step method, as illustrated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with so many things internet, it's all a matter of getting the right search terms. I used “unlimited canvas app iphone,” but then changed it to “infinite canvas app iphone.” The results are many and your decision will be based on how well you like the interface.

I played with one that appeared to be capable, easily understood for things like dragging the screen, erasing, changing colors, etc. It is called **Sketch Pad 3**. One of the reviews indicated problems, but my brief test shows no difficulties.

I did not install any of the other many choices available as a result of the search.

It seems like you may find something useful, especially if you don't insist on OCR related features.

Answer (score 1):

You should try **MyScript Calculator** from the ios app store. It gives you the whole screen to write on and updates in real time.

Comment: Yes, I’m familiar with that software. It’s quite cool, but it doesn’t meet my criteria.